# Do I have to put props to constructor because they are in mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs

In a component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ProfileForm from '../common/ProfileForm';
import { createProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class CreateProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            errors: {}
        };

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
        }
    }

    onSubmit(profileData) {
        this.props.createProfile(profileData, this.props.history);
    }

    render() {
        return <ProfileForm errors={this.props.errors} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
    }
}

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

I am setting the prop `errors` in the constructor but do I need to do so? The props `errors` is not used in the component and is only passed to the child form component `ProfileForm`. `errors` get send to the app's store when `errors` are returned from the `createProfile()` method.

Same with the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` lifecycle. Would that make for a better practice if I removed them?

Comment: no, you don't need componentWillMount, remove it, and the state in the constractor

Comment: the only case you want to pass props to super, is when you want to use `this.props` directly inside the constructor

Comment: using props in state consider as bad practice, https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e, you don't need componentWillRecieveProps and local state in your case, with redux when prop change render should be reactive. FYI if you want to pass down the props to children you can do <ProfileForm ...props />,

Comment: Yes, redux is making changes with immutable of data, so every time the new state is created. So no need store/setting up state as in the constructor. FYI if you want to change store data, then use local state management or to action dispatcher function call directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux makes the use of local state unnecessary. It's unwanted if global and local state affect same entities, `errors` in this case.

Since `CreateProfile` is just stateless container, `this.props.errors` should be used instead everywhere where `this.state.error` is currently used (it isn't used anywhere in original code).

`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and it doesn't serve any good purpose here because it maps `errors` to itself. In case there's a need to prevent unnecessary updates, `CreateProfile` can be made pure component.